# How to change from insert mode to command mode in Windows git bash

Tags: shell, unix, operating-system, command, command-prompt

When I completed my edit in insert mode,how to switch over to command mode in Git bash. I pressed twice to get into command mode..but the cursor is not available for writing command

Comment: Are you in a `vi` session? What key did you press twice? You should use `Esc`.

Answer (score 0):

To save the changes and exit fom vim `esc`  `:`  `wq` and `enter`

To discard the changes and exit fom vim `esc`  `:`  `q!` and `enter`